# Joomla Virtual Memory Overlimit 1.5GB in 2 days

Tags: .htaccess, caching, joomla, virtual-memory

Running on Joomla 2.5.24

I'm trying to diagnose why is the [site](http://www.prpg-tc.org.sg/) always hits its Virtual Memory limit. Current the host gave us 1.5GB of VM resources, but within 1-2 days the site will be down due to this issue and we have to reset it again.

I've checked plugins, extensions and they seemed to be running fine. The set of actions that I tried  was:

1. - proper cache (enable system cache)
2. - Enabled GZIP
3. - Editing .htaccess

I'm using Gavick Pro template and in the theme settings there are:

- GK Cache - On
- Css Cache - On
- Css Compression - On

Also I couldn't enable Joomla System - Cache because if I do, the content page will appear duplicated content  &  so I have to use GK Cache instead at the plugin page.

If anybody can share anything regarding Virtual Memory issue, please do!

[image: Virtual Memory Usage Screenshot]

Comment: Any error logs or exception being thrown on the server?

Comment: @isim hi error logs were just "File does not exist: - path"